# Regrouping two records in one record sql

Tags: sql

I have the following records for a specific employee:

```
  ID_Emp|Name    |Date          |TimeIn                   |TimeOut|InOrOut
   -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    11  |Jonh    |17/07/2019    |2019-07-17 07:19:36.00   |       |0
    11  |Jonh    |17/07/2019    |2019-07-17 17:19:36.00   |1      |
    11  |Jonh    |17/07/2019    |2019-07-17 08:12:36.00   |1      |
    11  |Jonh    |17/07/2019    |2019-07-17 08:30:36.00   |       |0
    11  |Jonh    |17/07/2019    |2019-07-17 17:19:36.00   |1      |
    11  |Jonh    |18/07/2019    |2019-07-18 07:32:36.00   |       |0
    11  |Jonh    |18/07/2019    2019-07-17 17:19:36.00    |1      |
```

The `InOrOut` represents if an employee has check in or out.

```
0 = IN 
1 = OUT
```

I want to retrieve the records as:

```
Jonh | 2019-07-17 07:19:36.00 | 2019-07-17 17:19:36.00
```

How can I achieve this in sql query?

Comment: You have more column headers than columns.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the check-ins and check-outs for a given logical date would always occur within that same date, then a simple aggregation query should be enough:

```
SELECT
    Name,
    ID_Emp,
    Date,
    MAX(CASE WHEN InOrOut = 0 THEN TimeColumn END) AS TimeIn,
    MAX(CASE WHEN InOrOut = 1 THEN TimeColumn END) AS TimeOut
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    Name,
    ID_Emp,
    Date;
```

I am assuming that there is only one timestamp column `TimeColumn`, and that you posted two in your sample data by mistake.

Comment: What if I have several adjacents ins and outs in the table for same employee? I want to retrieve all and calculate the hours between each?

Comment: Then you have a gaps and islands problem, and you should have posted the real data.

Comment: I have edited the sample data. Can you please help ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the rows are properly interleaved -- no adjacent ins/outs, you can use `lead()`:

```
select id_emp, name, date, timecol as timein, next_timecol as timeout       
from (select t.*,
             lead(timeOut) over (partition by id_emp order by timecol) as next_timeout
      from t
     ) t
where inorout = 0;
```

If you want the earliest time in/out on each day, then use aggregation:

```
select id_emp, name, date,
       min(case when inorout = 0 then timecol end) as timein,
       max(case when inorout = 1 then timecol end) as timeout
from t
group by id_emp, name, date
```

Comment: What if I have several adjacents ins and outs in the table for same employee? I want to retrieve all and calculate the hours between each?

Comment: Your second query is identical to my answer, and was added to your answer after I posted.